# USB Flash Drive gets disconnected after accessing a file

Tags: usb-flash-drive, data-recovery

I have a USB flash drive with >1000 files which gets disconnected after copying one file and I have to replug the stick.
I already tried it on several PCs with different versions of windows.

Is there a chance to avoid copying every single file?

Comment: I would get another stick.

Comment: Sure, but i need the files :)

Comment: Boot from a Linux LiveUSB in another port and you will be able to copy files to another drive. https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0